# Error: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery, autocomplete

I'm getting the following error: missing : after property id in line

```
data:{$("#msgForm").serialize() + "&field=msg_from"}
```

The code looks like the following:

```
$("#msg_from").autocomplete({
  source:
    function (req, resp){
      $.ajax({
       url: "autocompl.asp",
       data:{$("#msgForm").serialize() + "&field=msg_from"}
      });
    }
});
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your case it should be:

```
data: $("#msgForm").serialize() + "&field=msg_from"
```

in other cases, when using `{}`, you also need a key:

```
data: {'something': $("#msgForm").serialize() + "&field=msg_from"}
```

Comment: The first form is more likely the correct one as it's converting a form for being send: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `{` and `}` from that line:

```
$("#msg_from").autocomplete({
  source:
    function (req, resp){
      $.ajax({
       url: "autocompl.asp",
       data: $("#msgForm").serialize() + "&field=msg_from"
      });
    }
});
```

The `{}` in `data: {}` is interpreted as object literal, not a code block (terminology?). Object literals are in the form `{ id: property }`, hence the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Your data should look like this:

```
data: $("#msgForm").serialize() + "&field=msg_from"
```